# How to add after hover animation same as hover but in reverse transition?

Tags: css

```css
.mybutton1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6%;
  left: 1px;
}

.mybutton1:hover {
  transition: all 1.0s;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mybutton1">
  <a href="somelink" target="_blank"><img src="images/pic1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I don't know how to add after hover to class="mybutton1". I'd like after hover effect to be same as hover but in opposite direction  transform : translateX(-20px);

Comment: can you share your html

Comment: html is quite simple:<div class="mybutton1">

<a href="https://somelink" target="_blank"  ><img src="images/pic1.jpg"></a>  

</div>

Comment: Just move your transition property from .mybutton:hover to .mybutton1 and the transition duration will be applied for both hover and 'unhover'.

Comment: i'm newbie don't know how to do it

Comment: Change your CSS to this: `.mybutton1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6%;
  left: 1px;
  transition: transform 1.0s;
}

.mybutton1:hover {
  transform: translateX(20px);
}`